# Converting string to int in linq to entities on big database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i wana convert string to int in linq to entities but Convert.ToInt32 and int.Parse can not translate to sql 
And my database is BIG and can not get all of them to memory (over 60k record and get bigger)
my query is something like

```
int myNumber = 1390;
var result = from dr in myEntitiy.TableX
             where (Convert.ToInt32(dr.stringYear) > myNumber) // <== error
             select dr;
```

error say cannot translate convert method

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

whats solution

UPDATE :
If there is no way to do this please make me sure about this, then i have to change field type in database but it will be hard :(

Comment: Why do you keep the year as a string?

Comment: a stupid one did that :/ and i cant change that now

Comment: can you try to do the conversion first? Store the results in a list and then do your comparision

Comment: as i said its a big database and cant do this like (.ToList or .AsEnumerable) also database is on the web

Comment: can you use a dictionary? When you say database is on the web do you mean the cloud?

Comment: no , my mean , database is in the internet not a ethernet network or local network

Comment: if you can change the field in your database I would suggest that. It will be beneficial in the long run. if you ever have to make updates in the future you don't want to have to do this again. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is quite safe to do the comparison as string, unless you have years < 1000 or > 9999:

```cs
... dr.stringYear.CompareTo(myNumberString) > 0
```

EF translates this into a SQL predicate like

```sql
WHERE [alias].[stringYear] > @p
```

which is possible in SQL but not in C#.

An advantage would be that any index on `stringYear` may be usable in an execution plan. Converting `stringYear` to number eliminates any index.

This method is still useful when the string column contains jagged string values. In such a case the predicate should be combined with Length. For example, to find all entities where any numeric string as integer is greater than some reference value

```cs
var len = myNumberString.Lenght;

var query = 
    from row in context.LegacyTable
    where row.NumericString.CompareTo(myNumberString) > 0
       && row.NumericString.Length >= len
    select row;
```

Then the query engine can't use indexes for the length comparison but it might be able to do so for the `>` comparison.

Comment: ty , its work and solve my problem, i knew , '>' could use in sql to compare to string like int , but i dint know how it could use in EF . but as you mention its work just if length of field's data be same .let's see if there is a 100% solution for this, anyway ty

Comment: With years you'll be fine. The 100% solution is suggested by @ironman99 above: change the database field. I would make a very strong case for that!

Comment: yeah , if i could change database ,but i guess there is no better way than your suggested way, because there is no other way in sql to do that .

Comment: _Someone_ can change the database I suppose. Maybe it's hard to pull the right strings. Well, sometimes you have to settle with second best.

Answer (score 2):

This works, but the generated SQL will be messy

```
int myNumber = 1390;
var result = from dr in myEntitiy.TableX
             let num = myEntitiy.TableX.Take(1).Select(x => dr.stringYear).Cast<int>().FirstOrDefault()
             where num > myNumber
             select dr;
```

Comment: Looking for a similar problem, I found your solution the only solution, thanks :)