# run time error while converting string to int in entity framework 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

```
protected void GetFinalResult(IQueryable<clsProfileData> result)
{
    if (ddlHeightFrom.SelectedValue != "0" && ddlHeightTo.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        int from = Convert.ToInt32(ddlHeightFrom.SelectedValue);      
        result = result.Where(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Height) > from);
    }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework 4.0
and in above method `p.Height` is error causing conversion(string to int). 
is there any way to handle this ?

Comment: Why aren't you storing `Height` as `int` in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an error in converting a string to an Int32.  I couldn't find anywhere in the XML datadescriptions where the field was an Int32.  In the end the stored proc was returning that field as an int, not a string.  It's odd that the error messaged complained that it couldn't cast the data, in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

One advice: store the heights as numbers in the database, if you can. EF (currently) has no built-in functions to easily convert strings to numbers. Nor do [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx)* or [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) help you.

Storing numbers will not only make the querying much easier, but it will also enable you to write [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) queries. The `Where` with a conversion, as you've got now, disables any index on your column.

If you can't change the database, you may be able to use a work-around: you could store the numbers with leading zeros to make sure they all have the same lenght. Then you could use string comparison, because `00002` comes before `00010`, whereas `2` comes after `10` when sorting. Doing so, you can use `String.Compare` in your linq statement, which translates to `<` or `>` in sql.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10521557/861716

<sup>*[DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx) as of Entity Framework 6.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing for validity first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uk/library/f02979c7.aspx

(probably at the point at which you do this, as well:

```
Convert.ToInt32(ddlHeightFrom.SelectedValue)
```

)

e.g.

```
int from;
int h;
bool fromres= Int32.TryParse(ddlHeightFrom.SelectedValue, out from);
bool hres= Int32.TryParse(p.Height, out h);
...
```

Comment: Ok i tried this

if (ddlHeightFrom.SelectedValue != "0" && ddlHeightTo.SelectedValue != "0")
{
   int from;
   int height;
    bool bfrom = Int32.TryParse(ddlHeightFrom.SelectedValue, out from);
   result = result.Where(p => (Int32.TryParse(p.Height, out height) ? height : 0) > from);
}

now getting "does not recognize the method 'Boolean TryParse(System.String, Int32 ByRef)' method" error.

I want Int32.TryParse(p.Height, out height) to be parsed in single lambda expression only as i need all results to be parsed in same line of code.